# antd model loads very slow, and in antd table all operation sorting, filtering and pagination changes are also slow for large data set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

On dataView true dataViewModel is rendered

```
{popUps.dataView && popupsFactory.dataView}
```

Rendering of model is very slow, which have and table with dataSource around 10k-20k or more.

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
/* eslint-disable indent */
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Modal, Select, Table, Input, Button, Icon, Tooltip } from 'antd'
//import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import actionDispatcher from 'client/app-actions'
import { isFiltered } from 'client/routes/app/constants/deck-layers'
//import TableLayout from './Table'
import styled from './styled-component'
//import './style.css'

const { Option } = Select
const dataViewModal = (props) => {
    const {
        visibility
    } = props
    const [layerId, setLayerId] = useState('')
    const [tableColumns, setTableColumns] = useState(null)
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(null)
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')
    const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState('')
    const [filteredInfo, setFilteredInfo] = useState(null)
    const [sortedInfo, setSortedInfo] = useState(null)
    const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ pageSize: 20, current: 1 })
    const [currentDataSource, setCurrentDataSource] = useState(null)
    const searchInput = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
     // console.log(currentDataSource)
    }, [currentDataSource])
    /**
     * initialize layer
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        setLayerId(props.layers.length ? props.layers[0].uniqueKey : null)
    }, [props.layers])
    /**
     * whenerver layerId changes clear the sort and filter for the columns
     */
    useEffect(() => {
      clearAll()
    }, [layerId])
    const tempLayer = props.layers.find(item => item.uniqueKey === layerId)
    useEffect(() => {
        const layer = props.layers.find(item => item.uniqueKey === layerId)
        if (layer?.props?.coordinates) {
            showMapDataToUser(layer, false)
        } else {
            setTableColumns(null)
            setTableData(null)
        }
    }, [tempLayer, sortedInfo, filteredInfo])
    const showMapDataToUser = (layer, exportToCsv) => {
        const filteredColumnSet = layer.columnSet.filter(
            item => item.variableAdded
        )
        const showDataToUser = []
        const showColumns = []
        filteredColumnSet.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.showToUser) {
                showColumns.push(`${item.displayName}`)
            }
        })
        showDataToUser.push([showColumns])
        layer.props.coordinates.forEach((it) => {
            const showData = []
            filteredColumnSet.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (item.showToUser) {
                    if (it.geometry &&
                        it.geometry.data[layer.props.columnSet + isFiltered]) {
                        if (showColumns.includes('Network GMP')) {
                            if (item.columnName.toUpperCase() === 'OLYMPUS_ID') {
                                const splitLatLong = it.geometry.data[index].split('_')
                                if (splitLatLong.length > 2
                                    && !isNaN(splitLatLong[splitLatLong.length - 1])
                                    && !isNaN(splitLatLong[splitLatLong.length - 2])) {
                                    splitLatLong.splice(-2, 2)
                                }
                                const splitLatLongString = splitLatLong.join('_')
                                showData.push(`${splitLatLongString}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                            } else if (item.columnName.toUpperCase() === 'RETAINABILITY_KPI' && !isNaN(it.geometry.data[index])) {
                                const calculativeDCR = 100 - (it.geometry.data[index])
                                showData.push(`${calculativeDCR}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                            } else {
                                showData.push(`${it.geometry.data[index]}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                            }
                        } else {
                            showData.push(`${it.geometry.data[index]}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                        }
                    } else if (it[layer.props.columnSet + isFiltered]) {
                        if (showColumns.includes('Network GMP')) {
                            if (item.columnName.toUpperCase() === 'OLYMPUS_ID') {
                                const splitLatLong = it[index].split('_')
                                if (splitLatLong.length > 2
                                    && !isNaN(splitLatLong[splitLatLong.length - 1])
                                    && !isNaN(splitLatLong[splitLatLong.length - 2])) {
                                    splitLatLong.splice(-2, 2)
                                }
                                const splitLatLongString = splitLatLong.join('_')
                                showData.push(`${splitLatLongString}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                            } else if (item.columnName.toUpperCase() === 'RETAINABILITY_KPI' && !isNaN(item[index])) {
                                const calculativeDCR = 100 - (item[index])
                                showData.push(`${calculativeDCR}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                            } else {
                                showData.push(`${it[index]}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                            }
                        } else {
                            showData.push(`${it[index]}`.replace(/,/g, ';'))
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            if (showData.length) { 
                showDataToUser.push([showData]) 
            }
        })
  //-------------------------------------------
       if (!exportToCsv) {
        //create table data
        const columnNames = filteredColumnSet.filter(col => col.showToUser).map(col => col.columnName)
        const data = showDataToUser.slice(1).map((dataSet, index) => {
            //items[0]: array converted to obj
            const itemsObj = { key: index + 1 }
            dataSet[0].forEach((item, i) => {
                itemsObj[columnNames[i]] = item
            })
            return itemsObj
        })
        // console.log(data)
        setTableData(data)
        //
        //create table columns
        const sortedInfoNew = sortedInfo || {}
        const filteredInfoNew = filteredInfo || {}
        const columns = []
        columns.push({
            title: 'No.',
            dataIndex: 'key',
            width: 70,
           // fixed: 'left',
            key: 'key',
        })
        const len = filteredColumnSet.filter(col => col.showToUser).length
        filteredColumnSet.filter(col => col.showToUser).forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.showToUser) {
                // console.log(item)
                const columnObj = index === 0 ? ({
                    title: item.displayName,
                    width: 150,
                   // fixed: 'left',
                    displayName: item.displayName,
                    dataIndex: item.columnName,
                    key: item.columnName,
                    sorter: item.columnName ? (a, b) => sortByColumnType(a, b, item) : null,
                    sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
                    sortOrder: sortedInfoNew.columnKey === item.columnName && sortedInfoNew.order,
                    filteredValue: filteredInfoNew[item.columnName] || null, // to clear search
                    ...getColumnSearchProps(item.columnName)
                })
                    : index === len - 1 ?
                    ({
                        title: () => columnTitle(item, data),
                        width: 150,
                        //fixed: 'right',
                        displayName: item.displayName,
                        dataIndex: item.columnName,
                        key: item.columnName,
                        filters: getFilters(data, item.columnName),
                        sorter: item.columnName ? (a, b) => sortByColumnType(a, b, item) : null,
                        onFilter: (value, record) => record[item.columnName].indexOf(value) === 0,
                        sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
                        sortOrder: sortedInfoNew.columnKey === item.columnName && sortedInfoNew.order,
                        filteredValue: filteredInfoNew[item.columnName] || null,
                    }) :
                    ({
                        title: () => columnTitle(item, data),
                        width: 150,
                        displayName: item.displayName,
                        dataIndex: item.columnName,
                        key: item.columnName,
                        filters: getFilters(data, item.columnName),
                        sorter: item.columnName ? (a, b) => sortByColumnType(a, b, item) : null,
                        onFilter: (value, record) => record[item.columnName].indexOf(value) === 0,
                        sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
                        sortOrder: sortedInfoNew.columnKey === item.columnName && sortedInfoNew.order,
                        filteredValue: filteredInfoNew[item.columnName] || null,
                    })
                columns.push(columnObj)
            }
        })
       // console.log(columns)
        setTableColumns(columns)
        //
    }
 //-------------------------------------------
        // console.log(showDataToUser)
        return showDataToUser
    }
    const getFilters = (data, columnName) => {
        const uniqueValuesSet = new Set(data.map(dataObj => dataObj[columnName]))
        const filters = Array.from(uniqueValuesSet).map(value => ({ text: value, value }))
        return filters
    }
    const sortByColumnType = (a, b, item) => {
        if (item.columnType === 'NUMERIC') {
            return a[item.columnName] - b[item.columnName]
        } else if (item.columnType === 'TEXT') {
            if (!a[item.columnName]) {
             // console.log(item, a)
            }
            return a[item.columnName]?.localeCompare(b[item.columnName])
        }
       // console.log(item)
        return null
    }
    /**
     * set to initial values
     */
   const clearAll = () => {
        setFilteredInfo(null)
        setSortedInfo(null)
        setPagination({
            pageSize: 20,
            current: 1
        })
        setCurrentDataSource(null)
      }
    function getColumnSearchProps(dataIndex) {
        return {
            filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
              <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
                <Input
                  ref={searchInput}
                  placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
                  value={selectedKeys && selectedKeys[0]}
                  onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
                  onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
                  style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
                />
                <Button
                  type="primary"
                  onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
                  icon="search"
                  size="small"
                  style={{ width: 90 }}
                >
                  Search
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </div>
            ),
            filterIcon: filtered => <Icon type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
            onFilter: (value, record) =>
                record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
            onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
                if (visible) {
                    setTimeout(() => searchInput.current.select())
                }
            },
            //   render: text =>
            //     searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
            //       <Highlighter
            //         highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
            //         searchWords={[searchText]}
            //         autoEscape
            //         textToHighlight={text.toString()}
            //       />
            //     ) : (
            //       text
            //     ),
        }
    }

    function handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) {
        confirm()
        setSearchText(selectedKeys[0])
        setSearchedColumn(dataIndex)
    }

    function handleReset(clearFilters) {
        clearFilters()
        setSearchText('')
    }

    const handleCancel = () => {
        props.updatePopUpMode('dataView')
    }
    const handleChange = (value) => {
        // console.log(`selected ${value}`)
        setLayerId(value)
    }
    function onChange(pager, filters, sorter, extra) {
        //  console.log(pager, filters, sorter, extra)
          setFilteredInfo(filters)
          setSortedInfo(sorter)
          setPagination(pager)
          setCurrentDataSource(extra.currentDataSource)
    }
   const handleDownloadLayer = () => {
        //const layer = props.layers.find(item => item.uniqueKey === layerId)
        if (tableColumns?.length) {
        //export in csv
        const showDataToUser = []
        showDataToUser.push(tableColumns.map(({ displayName }) => displayName).slice(1)) // don't include key column ref: line 138
        const dataSource = currentDataSource || tableData
        showDataToUser.push(...dataSource.map(item => tableColumns.map(({ key }) => (item[key])).slice(1))) // don't include key column values ref: line 138
        let csvContent = ''
        showDataToUser.forEach((row) => {
          csvContent += row.join(',')
          csvContent += '\n'
        })
        const encodedUri = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/plain' }))
        const a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = encodedUri
        a.target = '_Blank'
        a.download = 'mapdata.csv'
        a.click()
        //export in csv
        }
      }
    const selectedLayer = props.layers.find(layer => layer.uniqueKey === layerId)
    const columnTitle = (item, data) => {
        const columnData = data.map(dataObj => dataObj[item.columnName])
       // console.log(columnData)
        const nullColumnData = columnData.filter(value => value === 'null')
        const nullPercent = (nullColumnData.length / columnData.length) * 100
        return (
          <div>
            <Tooltip placement="top" title={item.displayName}>
              <styled.columnDisplayName>
                {item.displayName}
              </styled.columnDisplayName>
            </Tooltip>
            <div style={{ fontSize: '10px', color: '#ff5c00a1' }}>
              {Math.round(nullPercent)}% null rows
            </div>
          </div>
           )
    }
    const LayerNames = () => (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Select defaultValue={selectedLayer?.uniqueKey} style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
          {
                    props.layers.map(item =>
                      <Option value={item.uniqueKey}>{item.displayName}</Option>
                    )

                }
        </Select>
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <styled.modelWrapper
        width="98%"
        style={{ top: '20px' }}
        title={<LayerNames/>}
        visible={visibility}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        footer={null}
      >
        <div className="Model Content" style={{ height: '590px' }}>
          <styled.modalContentHeader>
            <div style={{ float: 'right' }}>
              <Button onClick={handleDownloadLayer}>Export to CSV</Button>
            </div>
          </styled.modalContentHeader>
          <styled.tableWrapper style={{
                        overflow: 'auto',
                        height: '88%'
                    }}
          >
            {!tableData?.length ?
                            'NO DATA'
                            :
                            <styled.table
                              className="table-striped-rows"
                              columns={tableColumns}
                              dataSource={tableData}
                              pagination={pagination}
                              size="small"
                              onChange={onChange}
                              scroll={{ y: 410, x: 1340 }}
                              rowClassName={(record, index) => (index % 2 === 0 ? 'table-row-light' : 'table-row-dark')}
                            />
                        }
          </styled.tableWrapper>
        </div>
      </styled.modelWrapper>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (store, ownProps) => {
    const appViewState = store.appStore.appView
    const layers = store.layerStore.layers
    return {
        selectedLayer: layers.length && layers.find(it => it.id === appViewState.variableSelectLayerId),
        visibility: appViewState.popups.dataView,
        layers
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    updatePopUpMode: actionDispatcher.updatePopUpMode,
    updateCoordinateDataFilter: actionDispatcher.updateCoordinateDataFilter
}

const DataView = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(dataViewModal)

export default DataView
```

All operations like sorting, filtering, and pagination change are very slow. Filters take too long to render. Is there something I can do to optimize code. I tried to do calculation part of table dataSource before rendering and then passing it as a prop from Redux store, but that didn't work either.